# Share media content use facebook sdk 4.x+

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm make an example about using facebook sdk in android to post my status (include link, photo, video) to my wall.
Follow this facebook's tutorial link: [facebook startup tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android) I've logon and posted a link status successfully by ShareLinkContent class. But I can't share photo (SharePhotoContent class) and video (ShareVideoContent class) without official android facebook app installed. The tutorial don't require theirs app must be installed first, but I can't use my example app to post my photo, video without theirs app installed.

```
ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)
```

always return true regardless theirs facebook app installed

```
ShareDialog.canShow(SharePhotoContent.class)
ShareDialog.canShow(ShareVideoContent.class)
```

only return true if theirs facebook app installed

My code to share photo:

```
    public void sharePhoto() {
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(image).build();
    SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder().addPhoto(photo).build();
    ShareDialog dialog = new ShareDialog(this);
    if (ShareDialog.canShow(SharePhotoContent.class)){
        dialog.show(content);
    }
    else{
        Log.d("Activity", "you cannot share photos :(");
    }
}
```

Code to share video:

```
   public void shareVideo() {
    Uri selectedVideo = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "Video" + "/fight.mp4");
    if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareVideoContent.class)) {
        ShareVideo shareVideo = new ShareVideo.Builder().setLocalUrl(selectedVideo).build();
        ShareVideoContent shareVideoContent = new ShareVideoContent.Builder()
                .setVideo(shareVideo)
                .setContentTitle("Video Title")
                .setContentDescription("Video description")
                .build();
        ShareDialog dialog = new ShareDialog(this);
        dialog.show(shareVideoContent);
    } else{
        Log.d("Activity", "you cannot share videos :(");
    }
}
```

I've set my app's permission: "publish_actions".

Have I missed something? Or Trully I must install facebook app first before I can develop my app using theirs provided sdk (incase post photo, video)?

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you initialize the Facebook SDK ........
if yes then ask permission like this

```
Set<String> permissions = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()
        .getPermissions();

final List<String> PUBLISH_PERMISSIONS = Arrays
        .asList("publish_actions");
if (!permissions.containsAll(PUBLISH_PERMISSIONS)) {

    // pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(this,
            PUBLISH_PERMISSIONS);
    return;
}
```

then check will you be able to post a network image ...... like this

```
 ShareLinkContent content1 = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentUrl(
                    Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pk.wisesolutions.naatcollection"))
            .setContentTitle(final_messgae)
            .setContentDescription(
                    "Naat Collection App - listen to hundreds of naats free")
            .setImageUrl(
                    Uri.parse("http://apps.wisesolutions.pk/app/naatcollection/images/logo_180x180.png"))
            .build();

    MessageDialog.show(mContext, content1);
```

Comment: And facebook native must install on phone is not necessary.....if are able to share then check you bitmap by setting it on some image view.

Comment: Yes. I've Initialized facebook sdk and set my permission before, and if not it will relogin with publish permission. ShareLinkContent class always allows me to post status as url already, but I want to post my local photo and video using SharePhotoContent and ShareVideoContent, which I've checked and only working when I installed facebook native app (it will launch facebook app like sending an intent which contain extra local photo uri, video uri....)